# How to enable scrollable console?

Tags: windows-console

In Visual C++, I Created console using  `AllocConsole` function.
But I could not control its scroll bar using mouse wheel.
Only way to control scroll bar is dragging it.
It is too uncomfortable.

Is there any way to control scroll bar using mouse wheel?

Comment: Does scrolling with mouse wheel work in e.g. command interpreter console window (on your machine)?

Comment: This is not a C++ question. At best it's a WinAPI question.

Comment: Sorry @Tomalak Geret'kal. I edited tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  and disable `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT` and use `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`.

something like

```
GetConsoleMode(hConsoleHandle, &lpMode);
SetConsoleMode(hConsoleHandle, lpMode & ~ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
```